# Which Umbraco folders do I need to backup after deploying from VS and adding to version control?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, backup, umbraco, backup-strategies

I did the following steps:

1. I have created a new Umbraco instance by using the nuget package and visual studio.
2. I have deployed to Azure, using Azure DB as backend.
3. Installed the articulate package.
4. Added my project to version control (including App_Plugins folder, articulate dlls and so on).
5. I am able delete the umbraco installation and I can restore it completely from version control including Articulate.

Now I am starting to add content, articles, pictures and so on.

Think I do not need to backup the whole folder on the web server. I am doing regular backups of my Azure DB and I need some folders which are also filled with new content, like

- media (filling with pictures which I am adding to my articles)
- App_Plugins (keeping installed packages in umbraco)
- App_Data/packages (file directory for installed packages)
- App_Data/umbraco.config (keeping some content for Articulate)

So, is this everything I need to be able to restore the whole system by using the version control part, azure db backup and the listed folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I follow the approach as described in the question. I have added the following files and folders to the Visual Studio project and then later to version control (I have just expanded the more interesting folders which are not part of the project file by default, but needed when you redeploy the solution from scratch):

[image]

As described the backend is hosted on Azure SQL.

[Open Live Writer](http://openlivewriter.org/) makes it very easy to host article content on another ftp server.

By following this approach it is very easy to redeploy the complete solution, e.g. for umbraco upgrades or major changes on the site.

Comment: I use KUDU to quickly download my (zipped) files https://{you-web-app-here}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/wwwroot it works well.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally for data/contents you should backup media and App_Data folders. However, if you want to backup Umbraco site (including cache files) then I would recommend App_Plugins, App_Data, Bin, Config, Umbraco & Umbraco_Client folders.
Hope this information helps!